# Unable to pass database values to the redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

It is working.

```js
var userData={
            first_name : "My First Name",
            last_name : "My Last Name",
            email : "My Email"
        };
```

But it is not working

```js
var userData={
            first_name : this.state.userData.first_name,
            last_name : this.state.userData.last_name,
            email : this.state.userData.email
        };
```

this.state.userData has user data. It is showing in logs.
Here are complete codes.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import store, {history} from '../../store/configureStore';

import {CLIENTS} from '../../constants/entity'
import * as crudAction from '../../actions/crudAction'

// Import custom components
import AddClientForm from '../../components/client/AddClientForm.js';
import {httpBase} from '../../utils/httpBaseUtil';

class AddClientContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isFetching: true,
            userData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        httpBase().get('clients/'+2)
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ userData: response.data.data, isFetching: false })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error: ',error);
            });

        this.setState({isFetching: false })
    }


    /**
     * Submit the form.
     *
     * @param {object} formProps
     */
    submitForm(formProps) {

        this.props.actions.submitForm(CLIENTS, formProps);
    }

    
    render() {
        if (this.state.isFetching){
            return(<p> Loading...</p>)
          }
        
        var userData={
            first_name : this.state.userData.first_name,
            last_name : this.state.userData.last_name,
            email : this.state.userData.email
        };
       
        return (
            <AddClientForm
                initialValues={userData}
                onSubmit={this.submitForm}
            />
        );
    }

}

/**
 * Map the actions to props.
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, crudAction), dispatch)
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddClientContainer)
```

Note: My application is based on this boilerplate.
https://github.com/Bikranshu/express-react-boilerplate

Comment: please share your code in sandbox. and what error is it showing?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to share this big codes in sandbox. It also has nodeJS at backend which connected with MySql DB. 
It does not have any error. Just showing blank fields of forms.

Comment: Please see the data logs of this.state.userData 
https://www.screencast.com/t/surMy6QwwP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you set `userData` to empty array and `isFetching` to true in your constructor.

Then your component mounts and calls `componentDidMount` which makes API call then sets `isFetching` to true. At this point your API call is probably not complete which means `isFetching` is false and `userData` is an empty array.

Just remove last line in your `componentDidMount` method, also I wouldn't initialize `userData` as an empty array since its type is actually object.

```
 componentDidMount(){
    httpBase().get('clients/'+2)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ userData: response.data.data, isFetching: false })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ',error);
        });

    this.setState({isFetching: false }) // Remove this line.
}
```

Comment: can you please help me on this page. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59005564/11254362