# Passing Redux value to Material UI Radio Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux

It is the form that has problem
https://github.com/lukeclarkson/portal/blob/master/components/client/AddClientForm.js
And it is the form container
https://github.com/lukeclarkson/portal/blob/master/containers/client/AddClientContainer.js.

I added a new field to the form "Active"
It has database field "status"
I created component for it
https://github.com/lukeclarkson/portal/blob/master/components/common/form/renderRadioGroup.js

I am facing problem to pass redux value to it.

My text component is automatically taking value from the redux.
https://github.com/lukeclarkson/portal/blob/master/components/common/form/renderText.js

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract data from redux you can map the redux state to props. read the official documentation https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops and then you can access redux data in you component with props and pass in your radio group as this.props.nameOfYourProp

Comment: I already passing data in AddClientContainer.js and text field component is taking value from the data.

Comment: you are binding action not getting data from redux state read documentation

Comment: Can you please give me any coding hints. I am shifted from core PHP platform. As I am feeling if data is successfully binding with the text component then there should be minor edits in the radio component to fix it.

Comment: check this file how i used redux https://github.com/naveenkash/Movie_Database/blob/master/src/components/movies/movies.js#L150 state is your redux state